# Access violation writing location during File Parsing

Tags: c, file-io, access-violation

Ive narrowed the issue down to a few lines of code but im having trouble identifying what is illegal about the function call causing a "Access violation writing location" I was hoping someone better with C could help me out?

The input the code is breaking on is

```
vn 0.185492 -0.005249 0.982604
```

I want to assign the 3 float values to an Array of Struct vn

```
struct Normals{
    float vn1;
    float vn2;
    float vn3;
};
struct Normals vn[50000];
```

and the code that is crashing is

```
if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 'n' && line[1] != 't'){
    sscanf(line, "%*c%*c%f%f%f", 
            &vn[normCount].vn1, 
            &vn[normCount].vn2, 
            vn[normCount].vn3);
    normCount++;
    }
```

Any tips would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `&` before `vn[normCount].vn3`.

By the way, what is the point of `line[1] == 'n' && line[1] != 't'`?

Comment: Copy paste code. from one that had != on all the line[1]. Sloppy. And how did i miss the &. Ive been staring at this line for like an hour! Thanks!

Comment: :) Tip: Never ignore compiler warnings. (And a good compiler was telling you the problem in your code)

Answer (score 0):

the type of arguments supplied to scanf i wrong:

```
    sscanf(line, "%*c%*c%f%f%f",            
        &vn[normCount].vn1, 
        &vn[normCount].vn2, 
        &vn[normCount].vn3); // address
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(line, "%*c%*c%f%f%f", &vn[normCount].vn1, &vn[normCount].vn2, vn[normCount].vn3);
                                                                    ^^^^
```

You forgot an `&`. This is causing the value contained in `vn[normCount].vn3` to be evaluated as a memory address (which you obviously don't have access to write to).